# Can I un-squash in Git?

Tags: git

My merge request isn't approved by a maintainer because my branch contains multiple commits. It would've been reasonable if I hadn't checked the "Merge commits when approved" checkbox on Gitlab (I did), but they won't listen. I don't want to squash locally since I want to preserve the history without being forced to use reflog in case I need to go some commits back

Can I squash, push, and then somehow un-squash?

Comment: Squash is used for clean history, why to unsquash then? If you insist, you can make git reset and recommit small discrete pieces of changes again.

Comment: It looks like you are fighting with your team) Use soft reset for quick squashes.

Comment: A workaround is to make a backup branch or ref before squashing the commits.

Comment: Why do you need to go back commits? The work is done and squashed into a single commit. If you need to perform changes, add a new commit on top or amend the squashed commit.

Comment: @knittl, yeah i also don't get that sort of dancing.

Comment: Like the answers say: Git is distributed so you can keep a reference (probably a tag) for yourself. Probably name it after the branch name (which might have more traceability like an issue id in the name). I always make versions of my branches on the form `archive/<branch-name>-v<number>`. (There is an SO question about this approach but I couldn’t find it.)

Answer (score 3):

This sounds ultimately like a *social* problem, not a *technical* one, as you have two conflicting requirements:

- The maintainer wishes for your change to be represented by a single commit in the history.
- You want to preserve multiple commits which led to the change.

There is no tool in git which will give both of you exactly what you want. You will probably need to abide by the maintainer's policy, even if you disagree with it.

However, as others have pointed out, there is nothing to stop you keeping a local branch with the original series of commits. Simply run `git branch some-name-for-backup-branch` before squashing the commits and force-pushing the original branch.

Just remember that *this branch can never be merged with the upstream* as it would try to reintroduce the changes in the squashed version; it is useful as a historical reference only.

Since you mentioned finding commits in the reflog, it's worth noting that you can create such a backup branch retrospectively. Once you find a commit hash, as long as it hasn't been garbage collected, you can run `git branch branch-name hash` to make a branch pointing at that commit, e.g. `git branch before-i-squashed abc123def0`

Answer (score 1):

I'll share my approach to your problem.

1. I would squash my commits using interactive rebase (I use VSCode since it provides a good experience but you can choose other editors of your choice)

   ```bash
   git checkout your-feature-branch
   git rebase -i HEAD~<number-of-commits-to-squash>
   # Change pick to squash in the editor window that opens, save it and close it.
   ```
2. Push the squashed commits to remote.

   ```bash
   git push --force
   # git push origin +<branch_name>
   ```
3. If I need to un-squash the commits then,

   a. Locate the commit hash **before the squashed commits**.

   ```bash
    git log --oneline
   ```

   b. Checkout a new branch on that commit

   ```bash
   git checkout -b new-branch <commit-hash>
   ```

   c. Cherry-pick the squashed commit to the new branch

   ```bash
   git cherry-pick <squashed-commit-hash>
   ```

   d. Perform a rebase (interactive preferably) to split the squashed commit

   ```bash
    git rebase -i HEAD~2
    # change from pick to edit for the squashed commit.
   ```

   e. After following the above steps I would be in a detached state at the squashed commit. Then I would simply reset it:

   ```bash
   git reset HEAD^
   ```

   f. Finally I can recommit the changes in separate commits as needed.

Comment: Thank you, but boy is it complex

Comment: @loyax, I would do it like this. Maybe, you can wait for other answers if this can be done in other concise way. Having said that you can always reset it(that would be less complex). But as per your problem I provided my approach.

Comment: Keeping a reference to the pre-squash branch is simpler. You would have to remember what the old branch looked like (it’s not like there is a one-to-one mapping between squashed and... non-squashed) with this approach.

Comment: @Guildenstern thanks yes you're correct. Noted. Having said that I believe resetting it or maintaining a local branch would be another option.

Answer (score 1):

Applying KISS principle, I would merge the original local branch with the resulting squash commit and keep it locally like that.... If something else is needed, you can see what the work is about by taking a look at the local branch.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest is probably to create a new branch before squashing. This will keep the unsquashed commits in the other branch. Of course, once the branch is created, the branches are independent and you have to sync changes manually between them.

```
git checkout your-branch
git branch branch-unsquashed
git reset --soft "$parent_commit_of_your_branch"
git commit -m 'Whatever your commit message'
git push origin +your-branch # force-push is required, you have changed the history
```